# Tag watching & ignoring is bugged in the profile page settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-watching, preferences

On one's profile page, there is a *Settings* tab with preferences for *Tag watching & ignoring*, i.e. at [`/users/tag-notifications/<user id>`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current).

For both *Watched tags* and *Ignored tags* there appear to be two clickable buttons that are squashed together; the "Add a tag" and "Done" buttons read as "Add a tagDone".

[image: Watched and Ignored tags as seen in settings - with "Add a tagDone" circled]

Both of these buttons work (clicking "Add a tag" opens a text box to add tags, and clicking "Done" closes it).  But, as only one is actionable at a time, only one of these buttons ought to be displayed at a time.

---

Also, I don't see a good reason that the *Watched tags* and *Ignored tags* interface on the *Settings* page is different to that on the *Questions* page, i.e. at `/questions`.

The *Questions* page instead has a "Watch a tag" / "Add an ignored tag" button (or an "edit" button if populated).  This brings up a text box to add/removed tags (and is closed by clicking away).

[image: Watched and Ignored tags as seen on the Questions page - slightly different interface]

The *Questions* page also has the option to "Hide questions in your ignored tags" / "Gray out questions in your ignored tags", but strangely this option isn't to be found on the *Settings* page.

Comment: Yeah, the "Done" button shouldn't really be visible until the "Add a tag" button is clicked.

Comment: Corresponding bug report on MSO: [Messed up buttons in Tag Watching & Ignoring settings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424841/1478931)

Comment: If any changes are going to be made, it would be great to upgrade this to a [tag::feature-request] and ask that the "Hide questions in your ignored tags" setting appear in the "tag watching and ignoring" Settings page instead of/as well as the pane on the Questions page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure when, but this bug seems to have been fixed:

[image: Watched and Ignored tags as seen in settings - with "Add a tag" and "Done"]

This question can be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).