# New colors launched

Tags: discussion, design, announcements, accessibility

*November 21, 2023: To help with internal managing issues, you may see a reference number added next to the status tag on your post. These numbers don't determine the order or priority of issues but will make it easier for internal staff to log and track progress.*

---

**October 26th, 2023**

Thank you for all the bug reports, feedback, and concerns with this latest update. We have rolled out a handful of fixes based on those and are requesting more feedback on [the new post regarding those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394232/update-new-colors-launched).

---

It has been [a long journey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386102/accessibility-update-colors), but the time has come to finally bring our new colors to production! This post will serve three purposes:

- The first is to announce the launch of said colors and celebrate with the community who helped us get here.
- The second is to explain what we changed from [our last post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390761/colors-update-a-more-detailed-look).
- The third is to provide a space to report bugs.

### Our new standards

Our goal is still the same: we want to be more accessible without hindering usability and setting standards to ensure we reduce inconsistencies across our sites.

[As discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390761/colors-update-a-more-detailed-look), we used [APCA](https://git.myndex.com/) to guide our decisions. While we weren’t able to hit lightness contrast (Lc) value of 75 for all text, our large blocks of text do hit this and the rest of our text (with the exception of muted/disabled copy) will have an Lc value of at least 60.

At a high level, our light mode won’t feel that much different, but we believe that our dark mode has come a long way and that is thanks to the advice of a community member. Simply put, WCAG uses a simple contrast calculation that can not adjust for the human nonlinear perception and by using APCA our readability should improve for all users.

We’ve put much more detailed usage guidelines into our design system that discuss color usage, layering, emphasis levels, interaction states, and accessibility standards. We may not be meeting all of our own, new standards yet, but something we are aiming to do over time.

## Changes from our last post

From the last meta post, we made the following changes based on your feedback:

- Desaturated the blues and greens in light mode
- Changed the hue of green in all modes
- Darkened and desaturated the yellow in all modes
- Did an overhaul of the “background” colors in dark mode to more seamlessly blend with their foreground brethren.

Once we got in and started examining the sites we made even more changes. We noticed that there were certain scenarios where our dark mode blue wasn’t passing and had to make adjustments. We also still struggled with our brand color, orange, and had to make the sacrifice to no longer use it in the UI.

We added in a purple color so designers could have the unique color to use for new features and onboarding

[image: New Purple Palette]

### UI changes of note

The biggest change you’ll notice is the changes to the moderator and required tags. The moderator tags have changed from red to orange so they look less like an error state.

Then:
[image: Red moderator tags with red borders]

Now:
[image: Orange moderator tags with orange borders]

The required tags have changed from grey to a bold emphasis level of the site’s themed color. These tags were almost identical to muted tags, which we found to be a source of confusion.

Then:
[image: Grey required tags with grey borders]

Now:
[image: dark blue required tags]

Another change you will notice is that our toggles, radios, and checkboxes selecting component (dot/checkmark) will now switch to black instead of staying white in dark mode.

[image: list of checkbox and radio elements in various states]

Lastly, we had to lighten the meta theme a little to account for the new way we will do hover states. This will affect all meta sites themed with the black meta color.

Then:
[image: Black button with the word button in white]

Now:
[image: Dark grey button with the word button in white]

### Next steps

This was a big effort for just a handful of folks so if you find bugs, please use this post to log them and we’ll add them to our backlog. We hope to iterate on this in the future, thinking of things like font size and ensuring we use more than just color to represent information. We appreciate your patience and help as we’ve worked through this. We hope you feel it’s as successful as we do.

Comment: I like the new topbar color! I'm [looking forward](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11425/33591) to it making its way to [scifi.se]...

Comment: Does this bring dark mode closer to being available on other sites than SO as well?

Comment: Should site-specific bugs be reported here, or on per-site meta?

Comment: I found an SOfT bug resulting from this change. Can I post it here despite SOfT being off topic here?

Comment: @Mast From our developer... "Yeah, it gets us closer (particularly when it comes to custom themes having sufficient contrast), but we still got a ways to go to ensure a given site’s overrides play nice"

Comment: Note: [I posted the SOfT bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393960/1081494), but if there's a better place to send them, let me know and I can likely send them there too

Comment: Wow, so many bugs reported (some of them blatant) in less than 2 hours. Was this really tested before launching?

Comment: @hkotsubo Nearly 10k lines of code added, 10k removed, 113 files effected across SE Network, SO sites, Enterprise sites, and Teams tested by 3 designers, 4 developers. Yes, we tried our best to test every corner, but we clearly missed some.

Comment: 10k of lines added, 10k removed and 113 files affected just to change some colors and css stuff? Holy moly!

Comment: It just looks so washed out in SO dark mode, it's lost the vibrant colours that made important parts stand out. Did this really get reviewed or did the designers [forget about dark mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381873/158281) _again_?

Comment: i genuinely thought that my not-normal monitor i'm on right now was the reason the colors in dark mode looked so strange (and not in a good way). starting fiddling with monitor settings for a minute before I saw the post on this...

Comment: On SO, with the dark-theme enabled, the new browns for the "The Overflow Blog" box on the top-right of the page are really bad and "gaudy" looking. The outline is too bright. The remainder of the changes are "meh", way to pastel for my taste. Light mode looks a little better. The old color scheme was much better. Can you make it an option in preferences so users have a choice? The lesson of "If it ain't broke -- don't fix it." still has not been learned.

Comment: In SO dark mode the inbox count & rep change colours are so pale I wasn't sure there was any colour, accept check has no colour.

Comment: Also the deleted post background has a lot of white added to the previous darkish red trying to make it pale so that it becomes brighter than it was plus reduces contrast.

Comment: @Piper Yeah, that's a lot of work, but seriously, didn't anybody try to simply **access the homepage in dark mode**? Or check the colors of vote buttons? Looking at the bugs reported, many - if not all - of them seem to be basic stuff of the most accessed parts of the site, not hidden things in some obscure page. I don't mean to be rude and tell you how to do your job, but if the change is so big, perhaps you should've done a more comprehensive and careful test.

Comment: The issues here and in many other changes the team has made to the colors seem like the sort of thing that would be addressed by automated screenshot testing.  A human would need to approve the changes, which they would do after verifying that the change is what they expect.  For something like this, that'd be a lot to review, but then, it's a large change, and that time is time that doesn't have to be spent in repeated manual testing. It's unsurprising that with dozens of network sites with different themes, manual testing fails to catch stuff; that's where automation can lend a hand.

Comment: I can't speak to accessibility, but the new colors are unpleasant and look washed out in dark mode. I kept thinking my laptop had gone into outdoor-light overbright washed out mode.

Comment: @SquareObama I would assume (and hope) SE already has a suite of e2e tests using something like Cypress. It's trivial to configure it to produce a set of screenshot artifacts which would be a lot quicker to scan than visiting each page type for each site in each mode available

Comment: (My comments were re hi-contrast dark.)

Comment: @SquareObama I don't think it's realistic to roll out 98 sites _one at a time, every single time_ a change is made that could, conceivably, visually break some site.  Remember that this is a common codebase between all of them, and fixing a problem on one site could break another. My job involves working on common code that affects dozens of apps. These apps employ such tests, and they frequently catch problems and prevent them from reaching users. If I had to roll out my changes to each app and manually test individually, I wouldn't have time to do anything else, like actually making changes.

Comment: @Piper 'dark mode?' "we still got a ways to go to ensure a given site’s overrides play nice" and given "Yes, we tried our best to test every corner, but we clearly missed some." My experience with SE is degraded since the change has cause further regressions with Dark Reader. Why can't a foobar dark theme be released? Since either way my experience with SE is _already_ degraded.

Comment: @RyanM I don't fully disagree with you or Phil, I know clearly what I mean but perhaps missed the correct tone, sorry for that (deleted it now). I agree that automated tests really help a lot, but can't justify skipping basic testing, and won't solve the main problem, that is not related to tooling. Somewhat I disagree that opening a hundred sites would take so much that I would skip it only trusting the automated test. 5000 sites maybe, 100 we can open in less than a minute, at least for a quick glance (always with a rollback strategy in hand). Anyway, I don't want to extend too much.

Comment: So far, for me, the new colour style is actually an improvement. Have an upvote. Also, I don't know how much your team was affected by the layoffs, but kudos for managing to get this change out presumably on schedule.

Comment: Is there any flag to support the original colours?  I crafted a few thousand lines of CSS to create a perfect dark theme for ***every*** Stack Exchange site.  It worked flawlessly before this change.  I can write new code that is compatible with the updated upstream colours, but if there is a flag that supports the original colours, it will save repeating all that time-consuming effort.

Comment: If you roll out such changes, you should have made an option to restore the previous state (or you should have done better job at testing!). For me personally StackOverflow is completely unusable now, both in light and dark mode.  The high contrast toggle does nothing, everything is high contrast.

Comment: *"tested by 3 designers, 4 developers"* and not tested by single dedicated quality assurance team / person.

Comment: Relevant FR: [When implementing a major design / workflow change, offer an opt-in beta testing option before release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375588)

Comment: the colours on the dark mode are way to washed out... OMG

Comment: We have heard the feedback on Dark Mode. I posted a separate answer addressing that. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched/394021#394021

Comment: Ahh, that's a relief, thanks! I thought I was developing glaucoma until I saw this.

Comment: @NicoCaldo Its honestly hurting my eyes.  Dark Mode Stackoverflow is quite bad

Comment: Lovely, SO Dark Mode is a fixture for me, one of those things that come along and you wonder how you ever did without it.

Comment: @Piper Another change you haven't announced in this post is that the frame around the OP's username is removed in sites other than Meta. I dislike that.

Comment: I am sorry, what mess is the Dark Mode on SO? I really can't use the site, it is impossible to look at that, why did you change the colors? If it is related to accessibility, add an option about it... I did propose a new wider design for SO, and it was taken by "the community" as a negative change, I really do not understand "this community"... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406987/any-possibility-to-expand-the-view-of-the-page-itself

Comment: Not a single comment or update from the OP since the 19th, just a steady influx of new problems. Are these being addressed? Any chance of a roll back until the flood of problems is somewhat under control? Will clearer rollout protocols be put in place, or any of the very standard testing (manual and automated) suggestions be implemented?

Comment: Are pages run through automatic accessibility scanners like [axe-core](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core) to catch common errors like low colour contrasts before they reach production? Looking at the reported bugs, lots of them look like the sort of things I'd expect to caught by automated tests (or even component-level unit tests e.g. with [jest-axe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-axe))

Comment: use dark reader extension from chrome and use light mode, and then refresh the page. Color theme will be twisted and some buttons like "post answer" will disappear. You just need to undo this new change to fix the problem. The color theme is terrible.

Comment: @pilchard, The design team, is working on making adjustments based on the feedback here. That being said we generally avoid pushing fixes over a weekend.

Comment: @SpencerG thanks for the response, though I didn't actually ask why no fixes had been pushed. It does beg the question why such a large rollout was done on a Thursday on top of all the other concerns mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: @pilchard You asked if they were being addressed, so I answered that question. Fixes have been and are being rolled out for identified bugs; as far as critiques of how it looks, those are being considered as well, but not every complaint here is a bug. As with any rollout we will review what went well and what didn't and make adjustments where needed.

Comment: @SpencerG Thank you for clarification. Given the level of reliance on the community for debugging and quality assurance, I hope the *'review of what went well and what didn't'* will be made public, and some standards for future rollouts put in place.

Comment: I really feel sorry for developers who work in SO. There's a whole community specializing in criticism that reacts to their bugs almost immediately.

Comment: @Robert That’s a gift. It’s free testing. Free and instant bug reports. They’re blessed.

Comment: @Robert that same community is responsible for generating, moderating, and curating all of the content on the site/s

Comment: -1 on the new colors. As a color blind person now I'm actually lost on the site. Please bring the old colors back!

Comment: First I thought this new theme is a joke, like on april fools day, but this post makes me believe that it will stay. I quite literally don't want to have Stackoverflow open (I use dark mode, I'll refuse to use light or high contrast modes) because I need to focus much harder to navigate on the page which makes my eyes tired very fast!

Answer (score 112):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Some international Stack Overflow sites are almost unusable in dark mode

The new standards are causing problems at least on our site, Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt).

When using Dark Mode, many information are unreadable:

[image: Invisible mode]

Also, light mode leaks background. Not so obvious if your browser uses white as default, but it's not a guaranteed default.

[image: bg leak]

Please, can you revert until you fix and test it properly?

This [was also reported in our meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8901/tema-do-site-com-problemas).

Comment: We've shipped a fix for this one. Dark mode should be usable now. Thank you for the report and I apologize for the issue!

Comment: @DanCormier It seems the white background was properly added in the light theme, fixing the default bg leak.

Comment: @DanCormier: Sorry, no. _Scroll bars_ in code blocks are not visible!

Comment: @Gustav We've shipped a fix specifically to make Stack Overflow em Português dark mode function as expected. We're considering the scrollbar issue a separate issue (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393962/163535) and we'll expect the fix to ship on Monday.

Comment: [a lot of information, not many information]

Answer (score 102):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 459*

The 'compulsory' meta tags are much too weighty. They distract from everything else. Punchier than even the question title.

e.g.

MSE

> [image]

Ask Different [& others]

> [image]

If you shrink a page down so you're only really seeing 'selected highlights' then it's all you see… [well, that & the orange/yellow box, but that's mentioned elsewhere]

[image]

Comment: I don't think the compulsory nature of the compulsory tags is important enough to care about the visibility of the distinction. They're always listed first, so even if you care you don't need to visually distinguish them.

Comment: I've put the first part of this (required tags) on the backlog for someone to think about. Won't be one of the first things we fix, but we will get there.

Answer (score 90):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Question author's user cards are no longer highlighted on some sites

The OP used to be highlighted (usually in blue), but now they're not, making it harder to see who's talking in the comments:

[image: no highlighting]

In fact this is also making it harder for me to tell the difference between the question and its answers, especially when scrolling up.

For some reason, it still works here on meta.

Comment: On per-site Metas there is no contrast at all: https://i.stack.imgur.com/swnx0.png

Comment: Yes, now the "new user" also doesn't have any form of conspicuousness.

Comment: The CSS class is still there, but it only adds some padding now.

Comment: OP's name is also supposed to be highlighted in comments.

Comment: I don't think I've ever been used before as an example like this!

Comment: This appears to have been fixed as of October 26th.

Answer (score 70):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The brief flash when directly visiting an answer ([as demonstrated by clicking this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52)) is **EXTREMELY BRIGHT** in high-contrast dark mode.

[image: Navigating to an answer leads to AN EXTREMELY BRIGHT AND JARRING FLASH]

Comment: FOSC⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: @starball flash of searing chartreuse?

Comment: Yeah, this is a lot. I have a fix staged to bump this animation's starting color from yellow-300 to yellow-200. 100 less yellow! Hopefully that'll ease some retinas.

Comment: For me, it's too bright even without high-contrast. I'm just using regular dark mode, and the flash is really straining, especially when going through review queues and seeing the flashes repeatedly.

Comment: Reminds me of the [Pokemon Shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denn%C5%8D_Senshi_Porygon) incident...

Comment: @DanCormier Perhaps the flashing is an idea to shelve. You know which is selected, thanks to `:target`: is there another way to highlight it, perhaps with an outline of some kind, without causing the page to reflow? (You're going to need something anyway for the `@media (prefers-reduced-motion)` people: currently the flash is a workaround for the fact that the page jumps around loads.)

Comment: The fix for this is live. Hopefully the flash is still noticeable but not too intense.

Answer (score 65):

Low contrast on bounties text

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can it not be white on light blue?

[image]

Comment: White on light-blue is terrible on the eyes.

Comment: This is fixed now. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 57):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Inconsistent reds for review

In dark mode, the colors in the top bar are pink but the review indicators themselves in the drop down are the old red. This doesn't happen in light mode on sites other than SO, despite the fact that the top bar is now the same color on both. (I prefer the red with white text.)

[image: Pink on icon. Red reviews in drop-down]

Answer (score 52):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The color of the "voted" state for vote buttons seems to have changed. Now it has an orange border and is not filled in with dark blue.

Orange isn't Meta's theme color so I suspect this is a mistake.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Also, IIRC after the new vote buttons were introduced, people complained that it was hard to see the "voted" state of the button. So it was updated to be filled with a dark blue color to contrast with the normal state.

See image below:

[image: upvote button with changed color for upvoted state]

Comment: Meta sites used the "darker" theme of the button, while the "lighter" theme continued to be used on main sites. It looks like they accidentally copied the theming for main sites onto the meta sites. Also, it's not the first time that they've accidentally used SO orange instead of the site's theme color on sites.

Comment: It appears to be [the exact same color as the one used for the mod tag text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKz7r.png).

Comment: We've shipped a fix for this issue. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: @DanCormier I saw that the orange border was removed. But what about making the button filled with a dark color for meta sites? Meta sites should have the dark-filled vote buttons for the voted state.

Comment: @DanCormier Here is relevant answer by a staff member showing the vote button filled with a dark color: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389771/299995.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder @CaveJohnson. I've asked our designer who is out for the evening on how to proceed here. Expect an update within 24 hours.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I've mentioned this issue to our designers and they've confirmed that vote buttons should appear filled on Meta sites. I've implemented the fix which should ship on Monday.

Comment: @DanCormier I use Dark Reader on sites that don't have a Dark Mode - because I have eyesight issues. I cannot see if I have voted or not.

Comment: @DanCormier in https://music.stackexchange.com/ the vote button highlight color is violet, which doesn't seem to match the site theme, which is yellow-black-white.

Answer (score 46):

**Differing Contrasts In Page Is Hard On Older-Eyes**

Eye-strain with new color scheme in dark-mode is significant. After working with the new color scheme browsing questions, it is quite blinding. Either the background or the text foreground colors changed dramatically increasing contrast. The inline code in dark mode makes this worse. This is very hard on the eyes -- especially *older* eyes.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The eyes fight trying to resolve the green-boxes of answered questions in the "Related Questions" list. There is very little contrast between the value in the green boxes and the box itself. You can't avoid having your eyes being drawn to and trying and resolve text on the screen. The areas of "too much" and "too little" contrast create a lot of work to focus and really make dark-mode on SO a jumbled mess of colors.

To make sure you see that I'm seeing, here is a shot of the last question I browsed:

[image]

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 496* — For older eyes, after attempting to read though numerous questions, it just begins to look like a lot of glare on the screen and it takes much more effort to focus. Especially with the inline code shown in the main paragraphs. At full resolution, the inline code is literally jumping out at you. I hope you can do something to help soften the contrast there. It really is hard to read much with the colors like that.

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Nothing ventured, nothing gained, and I know a lot of good effort went into the new colors. This would have been a great project to preview or beta for comments before going live with. One general comment is the "outline" colors seem over-bright in dark mode. Softening the contrast there would also help. Keep up to good work.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) **Update - Horizontal Scroll Bars Missing in Firefox (Linux)**

With the new update, the horizontal scrollbars for code-blocks that extend beyond the div boundaries are missing on SO, e.g.

[image]

Comment: Hot take: inline code shouldn't have a background, or _at most_ a very subtle one.  There's virtually no benefit to it, it's disruptive to readability when used frequently (even correctly), and people abuse it for emphasis.

Comment: Compare what we got to [what we were told we were getting](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1vJxD-HiRCsU6tVI8--V54J_MUwxPKemP)

Comment: The Question List is close, but it doesn't look like the actual question pages were demoed or a lot of this would have likely been caught. What detracts from the Question List is the pastel (desaturated) reds and greens in the top bar to indicate Review Queue need and Rep Changes that add to the "too much/too little" contrast issues. I think it can be saved, it just needs tweaking. The unseen/visited Question List colors also are not as apparent as it was (white/light-blue). I can't remember what it was before, but I just know it takes more effort to distinguish.

Comment: @RyanM I do understand the sentiment - I especially sympathise with the misusing and overusing of inline code markup. Yet, having very little visual indication of what is or isn't code is also inconvenient. That was the case for a long while in high contrast dark mode - inline code markup would have *very faint* and often imperceptible background. Thus the most noticeable part would be the monospace font. This very easily gets lost in the flow of text, thus making things like "a variable" vs "`a` variable" harder to read than needed. Inline code does need to stand out. Maybe via other means

Comment: This isn't just "old eyes" and not just dark mode either. When starting up https://electronics.stackexchange.com this morning I thought the contrast on my monitor was acting up. Didn't notice it on other sites but that one in particular look all blurry and bleak.

Comment: I completely agree. They seem to have made regular dark mode into a high-contrast mode. I can't even see much difference now between regular dark mode and high-contrast mode except for the background color. This new color scheme is absolutely causing me eye strain and is going to negatively affect how much time I spend on Stackoverflow.

Comment: The horizontal scroll bars in code blocks are there in Firefox on Windows. However, my beef is that the code block scroll bars has extremely low contrast now. Black on dark grey just doesn't do it for me. (And, I'm sure others would agree with that assessment.)

Comment: I've updated this post with status tags for each issue/request. There was an issue with the value in the green boxes on "Related questions" that has been resolved and status-completed was added. Our design will discuss/review the background color of inline code (that got status-review). Most of the border (I'm assuming this is what you mean by "outline" colors) didn't change very much with the new colors — we mostly just did a swap to the new system. Re-thinking what has an outline or not would be a larger effort on a per component basis — won't be part of this color work. Scroll bar is fixed!

Answer (score 45):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Highlight color in achievement notifications is too dark

It seems like the highlight color for unread achievement notifications has unintentionally become darker than before:

[image: Too dark highlight color]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Eek! This is awful! Of course we can fix it. Thank you for your help

Comment: We've fixed this by lightening the background a step. The fix is now live. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 43):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Link text looks *just about* readable on a white background, but it's low-contrast against the blue background of the new contributor indicator. (A [convenient bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392049/308065) illustrates both cases in one image!)

[image: Unintelligible is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our unintelligible.]

Answer (score 40):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The scroll bars for code blocks are barely visible in dark mode.  The old ones were a light gray and now they are black on an almost black background.  Here is a comparison from the old version to the new one:

[image: side by side of the old version versus the new version of the dark mode showing the dark scroll bars]

Comment: This is a great catch! We have a fix in the works and it should go out within the next 24 hours. Thanks!

Comment: @DanCormier would be nice if the community didn't have to catch this kind of stuff after it goes out the door :|

Comment: I could hardly see the horizontal scrollbar, I merely thought that content had been cut off.

Comment: @mickmackusa me too, it was only by accident that I discovered it was still there

Comment: An update: The fix for this is scheduled to go out on Monday. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: They're visible again, thank you!

Answer (score 36):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

There's bad contrast in the sidebar: Grey on light yellow—even I, who barely have reason to criticise my eyesight, have slight trouble reading it on my screen:

[image: bad contrast in sidebar]

Comment: I think they're going for “unfocused / unactivated is light; focused / activated is dark” everywhere. Having consistent semantics is a laudable goal, but I don't see how to make it work here (especially not with the coloured background).

Comment: The [contrast value of ~73 Lc of that text](https://contrast.tools/?tab=apca&text=636b74&background=fdf8ed) doesn't appear to be appropriate for text that small; it should be darker, or bigger, or both... but to wizz's point there's also a semantic factor here; it would still be nice for it to be just a little higher.

Comment: There's bad contrast _everywhere_ now.

Comment: Also reported by Sonic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393963/946962

Comment: Our goal is to hit a contrast value of Lc60 for text. The lighter grey _does_ meet that standard on the yellow background. However, we've also recently switched visited vs unvisited link logic. So the lighter grey is only used for *visited* links (the goal being that they have less emphasis). The darker grey/black is now used for *unvisited* links. Hopefully this switch, helps a bit.

Answer (score 31):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 426*

High contrast dark mode looks closer to monochrome with washed out colours and less contrast than ever.
[image: Washed out more muted colours in the page in high contrast dark mode.]

Notifications are not drawing any attention now as the contrasting red has been replaced with white. And the grey in the background is now also white.

[image: Notification area with white inbox icon showing white notification for unread messages.]

Comment: That `#fce9e9` of the notification badges is about the faintest possible red you can have; it seems likes a strange choice in the mode that by-design should be the most contrast-oriented.

Comment: Regular contrast dark mode looks almost exactly the same as this, just with a different background color.

Comment: Feels like it's been left out in the sun too long

Comment: i even notice this on regular dark mode

Answer (score 25):

> At a high level, our light mode won’t feel that much different,

But it is different, very, very much different. I can finally read the green reputation badges :)

Overall, it is a good change, but it is not all perfect.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

My main complaint is about used black color on light themes. I think it is way too black and it stands out too much.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) For instance black top bar on some sites, including here on Meta.

[image]

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *(ref 459)* — Also black tags on per-site Meta. It looks like a black hole(s) staring back at me.

If you look at the Stack Overflow Meta screen, black tags dominate the page and attract attention even more than question titles that should be the ones that catch attention. I would prefer something less black that would be gentler to the eyes.

[image: Stack Overflow Meta]

Comment: It feels weird to create a usercript just so your eyes don't hurt from looking at tags, but that's where we're at right now unfortunately.. had to change them back to grey.

Comment: Agree with the tags on meta taking too much prominence, we're looking into all the tag styles, including the required ones here using a black background. For the top bar, we reduced the amount of variations in our darker blacks/grays, which resulted in the background now being slightly darker. I think the overall amount of "black" should decrease once we resolve the tags issue.

Comment: @Carog I understand why having single color happened. The point is that the choice  is too dark. While Meta bar is less of a problem than black meta tags, it still creates a very high contrast between such black top bar and light theme which causes eye strain for me.

Answer (score 24):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 459*

### The coloring for moderator-only tags doesn't have enough contrast, and I'm having trouble reading it

The color contrast ratio between the text and background color is too low, at only [3.88:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=CB6516&bcolor=FEF6F1). Given the small size of the text, the effect of this low ratio is that I'm not quite as able to read what's in the tag.

Can the text and border color of moderator-only tags please be bumped up to a darker shade, so it's more easily readable?

Comment: Or even flip them so they _start_ in the current hover state, and on hover, they lighten.

Comment: On our list. Thank you. Reminder, we are using APCA, not WCAG calculations so sharing Lc numbers would be easier for our brains to take in right now.

Answer (score 20):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

How is it that the blog's dark mode looks more like Stack Overflow than Stack Overflow itself?

#### Blog

[image: screen snap of the top of the blog]

#### SO Light

[image: screen snap of the top of SO in Light Mode]

#### SO Dark

[image: screen snap of the top of SO in Dark Mode]

Dark mode is effectively washing out all the colors other than links resulting in just a sea of blue links. There's no color balance, unlike on the blog where blue is used specifically for drawing attention rather than being the primary color of text on the page. (The sea of blue links issue *does* improve when you move on to anything that isn't a list of question or answer links)

Comment: [An update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394232/update-new-colors-launched) was made to the dark mode colors (more saturated to have less of a washed out effect). I'm going to mark this as complete, if there's still a specific issue with the new dark mode colors, please add to the newer post.

Comment: :shrug: doesn't look any less washed out to me.

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Some background colors are missing:

- Asker's user infobox

  > [image]
- Notice on answer box

  > [image]

Observed at least on Android.SE (+Meta) and Anime.SE (+Meta).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393956/241919

Comment: Some custom themes were generating values based off of CSS variables that no longer exist. We have a fix for this in the works. Thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 19):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 480*

The contrast between visited and unvisited links on Meta.SE hasn't been changed, and is still [just as poor as it was prior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376114):

> <sup>Top is visited, bottom is unvisited:</sup>
> [image: Questions page with two questions visible, the top is visited and the bottom is unvisited]
>
> The default color is `#4e82c2`:
> [image], and the visited color is `#36649d`:
> [image]

Obviously comparing them using an [APCA text-on-background contrast tool](https://contrast.tools?text=36649d&background=4e82c2) isn't entirely fair, since these aren't background colors– but I do think it still does a good job of illustrating why these colors are so difficult to tell apart:

| Visited Text on Unvisited Link Background | Unvisited Text on Visited Link Background |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Visited-link-colored text on a background of unvisited-link color] Contrast: 11.26 L<sup>c</sup> | [image] Contrast: -12.19 L<sup>c</sup> |

Can we please, please, pretty please get better contrast between these two colors?

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The text color for unvisited and visited links is reversed to what is expected: the *de facto* standard is that unvisited links are normal and visited links are lighter.

[image: screenshot of sidebar]

The "New colors launched" link and others that are 'dark' are visited.

---

Also reported by [MegaIng](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/388651/megaing) in a comment on [Sonic's related answer about the contrast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393980/946962).

Comment: Yeah, that's what confused me even more 

Comment: [tag:status-completed] now?

Comment: @Michael It does appear so.

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Rather poor distinction between accepted and not accepted checkmark colours for question authors

Not accepted:

[image: Checkmark button which is not pressed. Grey coloured.]

Accepted:

[image: Checkmark button which is pressed. Light grey coloured.]

For clarity, both side-by-side:

[image: Two checkmark buttons - left is grey, right is light grey.]

Brief animation of what toggling between the two looks like:

[image: Toggling between very similar looking colours.]

It is possible to think accepting does not work. [Maybe already happened.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426959/request-to-accept-the-answer-does-not-work)

Comment: *might* be a reason to have accepted marks green in addition to more highlight?

Comment: @Trish I'd say it's a good reason to have high contrast dark mode not look [as exceptionally desaturated like it does right now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393965).

Comment: [An update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394232/update-new-colors-launched) to the dark mode colors was made (more saturated). I'm going to mark this as complete, the checkmark should appear 'more green' when accepted in both Dark and High Contrast Dark mode now.

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 462*

The icon for the "run" button of Snippets has very poor contrast in dark mode.

[image]

It appears to be always using white, instead of the text color.
The class applied to the element to give it the icon is always `icon-play-white`.

Comment: The buttons used to be different colours to each other, as I recall. I found that useful: the obvious button was the one you're meant to press, and the other one was the one you always ignore.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Your recollection is correct. I had a tab open with the old colours: here is what it looked like [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs1pK.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E26v.png).

Comment: Based on the screenshots from VLAZ, looks like that icon was an issue beforehand (Eek!), added to the backlog (this one is likely to take more time). The second button will also be changed to the outlined version (there shouldn't be two primary buttons next to each other). Thanks for catching @wizzwizz4

Comment: @Carog The same thing's happened with the consent-to-tracking buttons in the square in the lower-left corner: I assume it has the same causes.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Correct similar but in a different area. Added to our backlog as well thanks!.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The double primary button resolved for code snippets has been fixed but not the icon so I'll leave the status-review tag on this answer until then. Example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73800420/how-to-wait-for-a-function-for-a-certain-delay-before-executing-the-next-functio/73800634#73800634)

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

1. Click on the SE icon in the upper right corner.
2. Click on Link to the Meta site of the current SE site.
3. The link gets an grey rectangular background

Reproducible: Windows, Ubuntu, Android.

Not reproducible: MacOS, iOS (see comments).

[image: SO]

[image: Ask]

[image: Movies]

[image: Italian]

Comment: Can't repro. If I click on the link itself I don't get time to see any change, I just get the new page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV1tV.png

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, I have about 1-2 seconds to admire this background before new page loads :)

Comment: I have to wait a second or so, but the image doesn't change in the meantime. i don't see that grey box at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tested on different browsers on 2 PCs. Same behavior. You don't have a custom script which may interfere?

Comment: Tested 2 browsers, same Mac. Can't repro. No user scripts at all on this machine.

Comment: Repro on Firefox + Windows 10. Happens for all Metas, except MSE

Comment: @Tetsujin Tested on Iphone - no grey rectangular background. But reproducible on Ubuntu. and Android.

Comment: Hmm, thats a weird one. I was able to reproduce it on Windows only, though.

Comment: Actually, I can reproduce it on a Mac too.

Comment: @DanCormier, but is it in fact completed? It seems like I still have this issue on both Firefox and Edge (both on Windows).

Comment: @DanCormier "status-completed" for 4 weeks now, but the issue is still present!

Answer (score 17):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Visited links in the community bulletin have too little contrast

When a link in the site's community bulletin (featured posts, hot meta posts, etc.) has been visited, the contrast between the link and the background is too low:

[image]

In the past, links in the community bulletin wouldn't change much between visited and not visited, as it wasn't that important to differentiate them in that block. Can this please be brought back, or an alternate solution to fix this problem implemented?

Comment: These are actually the *unvisted* links from what I can tell... Which makes this even worse, since now the intuition is the wrong way around.

Comment: Also reported by shaedrich: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393963/946962

Comment: @MegaIng Yeah, that's what confused me even more 

Comment: It looks like the color _may_ have been darkened a _little_. At least, it's now hard to tell visited links apart from unvisted links.

Comment: @MegaIng was correct, this screenshot was showing the _unvisited_ link style. We've since made an update to swap those colors. _Visited_ links will be lighter and the _Unvisited_ link is darker now. There is a bit less contrast between the two states now but all meet our goal of Lc60 on the yellow background. This was a change made to all gray links on the site.

Comment: @Carog Just when I got used to looking at the lighter colors for new things...  (nice change thou, ty)

Answer (score 16):

- Link brightness / contrast against the background is still reversed for dark mode on SO. Visited links should draw less attention to the eye (in dark mode, visited links should be darker than unvisited links). [I brought this up in the previous post](/a/390780/997587) and it was claimed to have been addressed, but it hasn't.

  My previous userstyle to fix this has broken due to the new CSS and with the new complexity (seems almost machine-generated) I can't figure out how to fix my workaround. I won't exaggerate and say the site is unusable to me now, but it's real heckin' frustrating and confusing, and even slightly anxiety inducing. Like- imagine if you woke up one day and suddenly the sky was green and grass was blue. Please just fix it.
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *(ref 481)* —  On SO in dark mode, the current colour of visited links (which is what I assume the colour of non-visited links is intended to be) is so bright that it's hard to differentiate from regular text. The brightness probably needs to go down for the hue to actually be noticeable.

  This actually *does* make some pages near unusable for me- particularly the New Answers to Old Questions 10k tools, where I rely on being able to easily tell which title links I've visited to know when I've reached the post I last stopped at in my previous pass of the content. After you've switched the brightnesses of the visited and non-visited links, please lower the brightness of non-visited ones so the hue is actually noticeable compared to regular text.
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) It feels weird that the button to change the saves list when saving something in a Q&A page is blue when hovered, while the rest of the toast banner is green.
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) I [still](/a/390780/997587) think the community bulletin is too attention-drawing in SO dark mode- probably due to a combination of saturation and contrast compared to the primary background.
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Did inline code in comments always used to have square corners?
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *(ref 482)* —  Wow. the background colour for unread reputation/achievement notifications is... *very* different than the colour for read ones.

Comment: The visited link colour issue happens [every time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381873/158281) they touch colours and every time they say they'll fix it 

Comment: (1/2) Visited/unvisited links: we pushed an update that reversed the logic for gray links to make visited feel less prominent. I've logged a ticket for looking at the blue links on questions in dark mode.

Buttons share the same styling for hover and in this case I understand it might be odd to see blue on a green toast but we're trying to create more consistency by having less variations in our buttons. This _should_ have been the case already before the new colors but it might be more noticeable now.

Comment: (2/2) We're hoping to update the Bulletin design altogether (timeline uncertain) and it was requested to increase saturation overall in dark mode, for that reason won't change the yellow color (used on the bulletin) for now as it might not be used at all in the new version.

We would not have changed the corners on inline code with this update so I'm assuming it's always been this way.

Achievement inbox: Agree, I've logged a ticket to decrease the contrast or try to match the notifications inbox style if possible.

Comment: @Carog when is the dark mode visited link reversal supposed to be fixed? I just tested SO rev 2023.11.21.1314 and it's not fixed. and what is your "ref 481" "ref482" supposed to mean?

Comment: @starball The reversal fix that went out was only for black/gray links. The community bulletin would show an example of this — black/gray links use our _muted_ style, that's what got fixed: in dark mode, visited links are now darker than unvisited links. If you're looking at the Review queue or New Answers to Old Questions 10k tools, the links use our _default_ style (blue link). That needs to be changed separately. It's logged as it's own issue. The ref# is to make it easier for internal tracking purposes (there just for me and my sanity) — I added an update at the top of this post about it.

Comment: @Carog my **primary** concern is everything else other than the community bulletin. so it is **not** [tag:status-completed]. It's **not** just NAtOQ. The default link styling literally applies almost _everywhere_ except the community bulletin. It's _way_ more disruptive than the issue with the community bulletin.

Comment: @starball Sorry for the mix up, there were a lot of other posts about the visited/unvisited links for the black/gray version (the community bulletin is the easiest example to find). I thought your first paragraph was referring to the black links and the 3rd refers to the blue links in your post so I split them up as two different requests. The "completed" on the first paragraph was for the black links getting the reversal, I have status-review on the 3rd paragraph which will be for blue links in dark mode. Sounds like it was all for blue links. Apologies for the confusion on my end.

Comment: @Carog no, they are separate problems both with the blue links. the first is about the brightness reversal between visited and unvisited. the second is that the brighter of the two link colours is _too bright_ for me to easily differentiate between it and regular text.

Comment: @starball I've logged it as an issue with blue links in dark mode overall and mentioned both points (and any other comments from others about blue links) that need to be considered. It's all under "one issue" on our end.

Answer (score 16):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I cannot see the numbers in the highlighted recent achievements menu in high contrast dark mode:

[image: Green rep adjustment on EXTREMELY LOUD AND BRIGHT blue background.]

Comment: It doesn't look like that for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Y0t.png you sure you are not running a userscript for that?

Comment: @M-- I disabled all my userstyles and userscripts to make sure. But no, it's exactly what I get.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393953

Answer (score 16):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 479*

I'm afraid I don't know about all the ins and outs of themes and accessibility, but this

[image: Screenshot of a math.meta.se post with an awful lot of orange]

and

[image: Another screenshot with lots of orange.]

are very hard on my eyes. (Windows+Firefox). I tend to think of orange as an accent color, and not really suitable for extended amounts of text.

It comes from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalisations-of-common-questions).

Is it supposed to look like this? Or is there some way to use different markup that would have a better result?

Comment: This seems like it'd be better if it were just a teeny bit darker. Here's 45% luminance instead of 52%: [example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qHHP.png), [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrbIy.png)

Comment: That's... a lot of links in one post. Maybe it's normal on the site you dwell on, but on SO that kind of link-heavy answer rarely lasts very long...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Yeah, that's not a typical post for math(.meta).se. (Heck, notice that it's on the meta for math.se, not the main site.) We get a lot (seriously, tons and tons) of duplicate questions there. And since there's almost no support for site-specific FAQs, that post is an attempt to put answers to frequently asked questions in one place. So it definitely pushes the link-color question hard....

Comment: That said, a more average question, like [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36001/what-should-i-do-with-my-downvoted-duplicate-post) (check out the answer), still makes me think that orange is not a good color choice for links in bodies of text. (And this is only on math.meta, not regular math. But meta questions are often link heavy - you're often pointing people to previously-stated policies.)

Comment: Oh yeah, don't get me wrong, orange is not a good color for links or any text beyond some accent display text. Duplicates are a bane everywhere with little support forthcoming for SE it appears...

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this is a theme specific issue and was in fact an issue before colors, correct? No theme-specific colors should have been affected.

Comment: @Piper You appear to be correct. [Here is the page before the update](https://web.archive.org/web/20221126164744/https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalisations-of-common-questions); the relevant colors look identical to me.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The count of CM escalations on a user's profile when viewed by a moderator is extremely low-contrast in dark mode:

[image: White-on-light-grey "3" in a box]

Comment: I posted a separate answer addressing the dark mode feedback. Linking to it here so it's easier to find. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched/394021#394021

Comment: @Rosie This is a separate, unrelated issue.  That answer addresses elements that are have sufficient contrast, but are for whatever reason visually unappealing.  [These colors are, per APCA, unsuitable for text at any size](https://www.myndex.com/APCA/?BG=ffffff&TXT=c8ccd0&DEV=G4g&BUF=A22).

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)  *ref 459*

The contrast between tags and the background colour for "watched tag" questions on the Stack Overflow home page in dark mode is just terrible

[image: tags on watched bg]

You can barely distinguish the tags.

It's not much better for unwatched tags

[image: tags on regular bg]

or on the question pages themselves

[image: question tags]

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Why does the "Related questions" section for unanswered questions have one font color for the numbers, but the one for the answered section has a different font color (non-contrasting, by the way)?

A "Related questions" section for an unanswered question:

[image]

And for answered questions:

[image]

The same is true for the 'linked' section

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The new dark mode has all the colors washed out. The orange is really bad...

[image]

Comment: I posted a separate answer addressing the feedback on dark mode. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched/394021#394021

Comment: An update to the dark mode colors was made (more saturated). I'm going to mark this as complete, if there's still an issue, please leave feedback on the [updated post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394232/888623).

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [Help Center article 'How do I use tags to find topics I'm interested in?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) still uses screenshots of the old design:

> [image]

The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHYXK.png) of the [article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) about inline tag-edits also uses the old design.

Comment: Thanks will flag this for us to update.

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

"Looking for your Teams?" element isn't centered. (Maybe not new, but it stands out more to me now.) The screenshot is from Stack Overflow but the same is happening here.

[image]

Comment: This may be the cause of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393940/1081494

Comment: It was like that [earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388370/339911)

Comment: Looks like this is fixed now, thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 459*

### Give us back the border for normal tags, as the background isn't rendered on high-contrast monitors

When a user's monitor is set to a high contrast level (such as if they want text to "pop out" more easily for accessibility, really light colors tend to blend into the background. This would happen with the current background color for normal (non-required, non-moderator-only) tags.

In the older style, there used to be a border around normal tags, but this seems to have been removed. Without it, on high-contrast monitors, the tags would appear as plain text rather than tags.

Can the border around normal tags please be added back?

Comment: I've added it to our backlog

Comment: @Piper Thanks! It would be really cool if you edited in status tags into each answer here with tags, on top of responding in the comments, so the status of them is clearer.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog just for clarity: are you using the high contrast mode set in the Stack settings, an OS-level high contrast mode, or do you have a special monitor setting for high contrast? Or multiple/none of those? To get this one correct, it would be helpful to understand your circumstances a little better.

Comment: @DanCormier Monitor setting. On most desktop monitors if you dial the contrast all the way to 100 you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The relatively small color change makes my eyes have to work harder to read blue-on-blue:

| old | new |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I haven't checked, but it feels like the background and foreground colors are closer than before and it puts a strain on my eyes.

Comment: This is made worse by the name appearing twice due to the [incorrect markup for the profile picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379431/165261)

Comment: @RyanM Aha, is that was that is. I've been wondering about that :-)

Comment: There was an update to our dark mode colors (more saturated) and the background of the usercard that should have helped with the contrast here.  It looks much clearer on my monitor now (compared to the "new" screenshot you shared), so I'll mark this as completed. Let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: @Carog Indeed! The colors are much better than they were when I posted this, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) *ref 474 and 476*

The 404 pages are lighter grey than expected when using high-contrast dark mode, and are not consistent with other pages such as undeleted posts or the home page.

[image: Image of 404 page with a lighter grey background than expected]

And while we are at it the close and flag dialog are also this lighter grey even with high-contrast enabled. This is not very high contrast as I would expect with high-contrast mode:

[image: Image of a low contrast flag dialog in high-contrast mode]

Comment: The close panel is an issue [in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaWeK.png) as well.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, the issue has been logged. Background adjustments will be made to get a 7:1 contrast ratio for HC mode for both the 404 page and the modals.

Comment: @Carog Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

People have already mentioned aspects of this, but the overall conclusion I draw is that

### Yellow is not the new black.

It's awful for contrast, but it's not the greys that are the problem, it's the yellow.
Everywhere this yellow appears it's far too punchy. It's meant to be a gentle highlight, not
**"Your attention is required right here, immediately!"**

[image]

This one took some effort to screen-cap, the highlighted question you see on page refresh, but this is truly horrible.

[image]
<sub>Intentionally small, you don't need to read it.</sub>

I'm on a fully colour-calibrated machine here, I hate to think what this will look like on the usual consumer over-punchy laptop screen.

Comment: As far as the flash, a fix has been made in the source but hasn't been pushed out to production yet.

Comment: That's good to hear - but it's everywhere this new yellowy-orange is used. It's just far too punchy.

Comment: Also reported by sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393980/387876

Comment: These examples seem to be referring to our yellow, not orange so I've edited your post to reflect that. We did struggle a lot with finding the right balance between making the yellow color work with our contrast standards and still look "yellow". We have no plans to change the yellow color at this time.

Comment: The yellow flash fix should be live now, the yellow background on watched posts was reduced to a lighter (less vibrant) stop as well and there's a fix for reducing the yellow background on Saves/Collection notes in the backlog. Hopefully this all helps remove some of the yellow prominence a bit. In regards to the community bulletin, [it sounds like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390761/colors-update-a-more-detailed-look/390780#comment1305590_390780) having it call more attention isn't such a bad thing.

Answer (score 13):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) *ref 484*

Two buttons in the same header are two different blues. It may be that they have slightly different semantics but the color difference is too subtle to indicate that and rather just looks like an error.

---

[image]

---

The custom properties at question are

```
--_bu-filled-bg-selected  //rgb(21, 92, 162))
```

and

```
--_bu-filled-bg  //rgb(27, 117, 208)
```

Comment: Agree, the Watch/Unwatch button should be using the outlined class instead, an issue had been logged.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Cross-posting from [RPG.Meta.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12496/4563); this is a color bug specific to RPG.SE.

> So Stack Exchange got new colors, and there’s a [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393939/190917) Q&A about it, but this issue seems to be specific to our site: questions with watched tags get a color highlight, but the contrast between it and regular questions is quite slight, so those questions don’t actually stand out the way they should:
>
> [image: Image from RPG.SE main page showing several questions, two with watched tags and three without, showing the limited contrast between the two]
>
> This hasn’t been mentioned on the Meta.SE Q&A because most sites don’t have this problem: their contrast is greater:
>
> [image: Image from Meta.SE main page showing three questions, one with a watched tag, to show the greater contrast]
>
> The cause here is pretty clear, too: all sites use `--yellow-100` for this highlight color, but our site uses a different background color for regular questions that is much more yellow-ish (`#FFFDF7`) and thus much closer to `--yellow-100` than the white (`#FFFFFF`) used on most sites. We need either a custom `--yellow-100` (and presumably customizations to the other `--yellow-###` colors to correspond appropriately), or we need a custom rule that doesn’t use `--yellow-100` for these questions.

Comment: The contrast in Stack Overflow dark mode is similarly bad, if not worse.

Comment: See also [ELU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP5mT.png), which also has a beige background.

Comment: We've made a small update to our yellow-100 color. The contrast ratio should be much closer to what RPG had before with contrast between the custom background color and posts with watched tags. Adding a custom color for watched backgrounds isn't an easy fix so I would suggest asking for an update the RPG site background color on RPG meta.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 497*

In the flagging history, questions and answers which are deleted should be shown with a red background (answers are shown as the question title but in smaller text). For some reason, deleted **answers** do not have the red background anymore but deleted **questions** still do.

Both the question and the answer in this screenshot are deleted:

[image: Inconsistent red background on deleted question vs deleted answer]

Note: The screenshot uses Stack Overflow Dark Mode but this also applies in light mode.

Comment: Side note: I am not sure if the text in the spam and rude flags are supposed to be black in dark mode so this may be another bug

Comment: If you inspect the html you'll see that it uses the `bg-red-050` class... which, from initial investigation, does not exist.  It seems it might be a typo of `bg-red-150`.

Comment: @Daedalus Previously they had `050` variables. It looks like they removed those in the latest update to the new colors.

Comment: @Daedalus They changed the names of all the `050` variables, except `--black-050` to include `-legacy`, so `--red-050` is now `--red-legacy-050` (black has *both* `--black-legacy-050` and `--black-050`. All of the associated classes which stood in for a single `050` color assignment also had `-legacy` added, so there's now a `bg-red-legacy-050` class, along with `:hover`, `:focus` variants using `h\:` and `f\:` prefixes on the class names.

Comment: @Carog Thanks! Finally this may be fixed.

Answer (score 11):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 486*

Were the green/ red diff highlight colors (e.g. that show up [in revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/393939/revisions)) touched at all? The green looks darker to my eyes, and the contrast is somewhat poor, but I have no idea whether this was actually adjusted or not:

> [image: Revisions page showing red and green highlighting throughout the diff]

Both colors are a little difficult to read and roughly on par with each other, with an L<sup>c</sup> score of about 60 each ([Red: 60.17](https://contrast.tools?tab=apca&text=5d1414&background=eeaaaa), [Green: 59.71](https://contrast.tools?tab=apca&text=0a4324&background=94ccae)). Given, I do understand that this text isn't designed to be read quite the same way as standard body text, but it caught my eye and seemed worth calling out.

Dark mode colors appear to fare... about the same, if marginally better by the numbers at ~67 ([Dark mode red: -65.96](https://contrast.tools/?tab=apca&text=636b74&background=fdf8ed), [Dark mode green: -67.73](https://contrast.tools/?tab=apca&text=e6f4ed&background=4d8064)):

> [image: Another revisions page showing both diff colors, this time in Stack Overflow dark mode]

Comment: *" I do understand that this text isn't designed to be read quite the same way as standard body text"* I disagree; it very much is meant to be read in the same way as standard body text, at least when reading the revision history.  I agree with you that this is hard to read, and could be improved (especially for suggested edit review, assuming it uses the same colors).

Comment: I struggled with cognitive overload when reviewing suggested edits under the previous design: seconding that we shouldn't make it even worse.

Comment: Our main struggle with diff highlight colors is getting 3 shades of the same color to work and still be legible — in some cases we have 2 background shades of red and 1 shade for text all on top of each other (that still needs to pass contrast standards). However, in a lot of cases we only need 2 shades like your screenshot (1 background shade and 1 text shade) so I'll see if there's a graceful way to improve our 2 shaded use cases without breaking the 3 shaded cases.

Answer (score 11):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) *ref 488*

Background too dark on highlighted sections of comment formatting help:

[image]

The dark background

```
.comment-help code {
    background-color: var(--blue-400) !important;
}
```

is a bit too dark against black text, perhaps lightening it up to:

```
.comment-help code {
    background-color: var(--blue-300) !important;
}
```

[image]

is in order?

At the very least, this problem present on this site and SO.

Comment: Ooff that's bad and even worse in HC mode, thanks for reporting. Agree with the suggested change, I've logged to make updates to both default and High Contrast mode to make sure we meet contrast standards.

Answer (score 10):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 459*

The contrast between the new moderator tag color scheme and the question-with-watched-tag background highlight is somewhat poor:

> [image: Question on the questions page with a watched tag, with the highlighted background that comes with it]

Answer (score 10):

The "Share" link stands out from the other buttons under a post when marked as visited:

[image: The "Share" link under a post is noticeably lighter than the other links in high contrast dark mode.]

Answer (score 10):

[Keyboard shortcut highlights are still invisible in high contrast dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420420)

Here is a static screenshot of the question list:

[image: List of posts where the second one is supposed to be highlighted via a selection with a keyboad shortcut. All posts look exactly the same.]

When pressing <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd> to select different posts it looks exactly the same. Thus I cannot bother with capturing a GIF this time.

One of those posts is indeed selected. To help you find which one, here is a hint: it has the CSS style

```css
.keyboard-selected {
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset;
}
```

while the normal background colour is `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, so there should be a partially see-through completely black shadow on the completely black background.

Comment: The eye-strain for the new colors in dark-mode is blinding....

Comment: It is worth noting that high-contrast dark mode is intended to help with accessibility, which keyboard navigation is _also_ supposed to help with...so it's particularly bad for it not to work in this mode.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [chat](/questions/tagged/chat)

Something about this rollout seems to have messed up the contrast on the chat.SE topbar. The username and "mod" links are now very difficult to read:

[image: The chat.SE topbar with the "Mithical♦" and "mod" links very difficult to read]

I've verified that this is not being caused by any userscripts.

The same thing happens on chat.Meta.SE.

It's entirely impossible to see on chat.SO:

[image: chat.SO with nothing visible where the user link is]

The link is still there but it's impossible to see.

Comment: For me it is just username - as I am not a moderator. But I can confirm that it looks the same for me; the username is almost invisible. (I was about to report this problem - I am glad to see that it is already reported.)

Answer (score 10):

Not a bug, but an annoyance.

I'm sure I'm not the only one here using [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) to cope with SE's archaic lack of a Dark Mode.
Before this update I was able to clearly see whether or not I had voted on a question, but now I can barely tell, except for the slightly brighter outline of the button:

[image]

<sup>↑ This is an upvote</sup>

Trying to figure out why this happens:

A `theme-base-primary-color` is added to the colour scheme (disabling it reveals that the underlying color palette is likely that for Stack Overflow; disabling `--theme-base-primary-color-l` turns Meta's color scheme orange [which could also explain why Dark Reader sometimes shows the banners here as orange rather than blue, but I digress]).
The culprits seem to be the orange values (specifically `--orange-100` and `--orange-500`) in `body:not(.theme-highcontrast):not(.theme-dark)`), but I can't figure out why they aren't changed or even changed by Dark Reader.

This also brings up a second matter: why is the CSS for SE so convoluted? Why are so many overlapping and hierarchized style changes being parsed on every single site? Can't individual domains trigger their own specific code blocks?

Comment: The CSS is convoluted because the HTML has just been _evolving_ for the past two decades, and is far too convoluted to use CSS selectors on easily, so the styling has to be inline in the HTML. [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/) is rather impressive for what it is (a better, more domain-specific Bootstrap), and they've been chipping away at making individual pages… perhaps not all that much _better_, but certainly more consistent. Individual sites used to trigger their own specific code blocks, but they found that too hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for raising this. I also use Dark Reader for most SE sites (I use the official dark mode on SO), but I've had to disable Dark Reader because of this vote button issue.

Comment: @Robotnik As a workaround, I've set Dark Reader to use "Filter" instead of the "Dynamic" theme generation mode for SE sites. It's uglier but it's easier to see whether I've voted on a question while having dark mode.

Comment: @galacticninja Oof, yeah, filter mode is pretty ugly, but thanks, at least my eyes aren't burning and I can see if I've voted now :)

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Stack Exchange Toolbar - Stack Exchange Menu

When editing **YOUR COMMUNITIES**  the **ADD** button is "invisible"

[image: Stack Exchange dropdown - edit mode]

Steps to reproduce

1. Sign in to a Stack Exchange account.
2. Go to any Stack Exchange site.
   I check this on:

   - Meta Stack Exchange
   - Webmasters SE
   - Web Applications SE
3. Click the Stack Exchange Menu > (YOUR COMMUNITIES section) Edit.
   This should display something like the above snapshot.

#### Environment

- Mac Mini M1
- Chrome with several extensions, like Grammarly, TamperMonkey, Diigo and others.
  The extensions that modify the styles of general sites, like Stylebot and TamperMonkey are turned off. I didn't try on Incognito with all the extensions disabled.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394268/997587

Comment: Now fixed, as per Carog's response on the post linked above and on this post: [The "Add" button on the "A list of all 183 Stack Exchange Sites" menu is not visible until you hover over it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395684/335251)

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 498*

#### Duplicated border in help center

The navigation menu on the right side of [this help center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) (and likely others) has a duplicated and offset top border. Can it be removed, as it looks weird?

Actually, this seems to be more general. I also see it on Custom Filters, Watched Tags, Featured on Meta, and "disclaimers" (i.e., on law.SE), so it might be an issue with the boxes more generally.

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing something a bit different on my end but there's definitely something weird going on with extra borders. I've logged it with the team to investigate.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag didn't get the new design: (for some it did, based on comments.)

[image: featured tag still with previous design]

According to this very announcement, it should be very different:

[image: featured tag as it should look like]

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but it _does_ have it, I think. Wasn't it red before?

Comment: @CDR heh let me hard refresh... nope, that's what I see, even after clearing cache. That's on the server side. Maybe the new CDN, i.e. based on location, caching old CSS.

Comment: @CDR: Yep, it was. It's definitely changed.

Comment: In your screenshot, the tag you circled looks like it has the new color, doesn't it? It seems to be orangeish now.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I honestly can't see any difference from before. It was exactly like that, maybe different tint of red. According to the post, it should be blue, so really don't know what's going on.

Comment: The "featured" tag is a mod-only tag (orange), not a required tag (blue). **Edit:** oh, I see, yeah, something's wrong (either the announcement or the implementation).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. that's not what the announcement says, they clearly claim to change it. It's mod-only, but special as it's not related to the status, so always caused trouble. ;)

Comment: Featured is a mod tag and should be orange. I took a quick screenshot from internal documents so my screenshot is wrong and the current implementation is correct. I'll fix my post.

Comment: Added the status-completed tag since the screenshot has been corrected has on the post.

Comment: @Carog thanks, but I wonder about "you may see a reference number added next to the status tag on your post" - this is pretty big change, maybe worth announcing it on its own, not as part of colors update which isn't really related?

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry So far I'm only doing it on the 2 color posts. I'm testing out a new process for keeping track of issues that came up from the color change specifically. If it helps and we want to keep doing it in the future on all posts, we'll announce something more general on meta. The team/process for managing issues related to colors is a bit different than the usual so it might just be an edge case.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 459*

When I view a deleted post ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393991)), the contrast between the red/pink background and the tags isn't great.

[image]

I don't have a specific suggestion in mind, but is there a way to increase the contrast between the red background and the tags (other than something like a userscript)?

Comment: Not great in dark mode either https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np7zU.png

Comment: Agree, don't love this. I think we can play around with it.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Horizontal scrollbar in topbar is too hardly visible on dark mode with narrow screen on mobile:

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

The one I've visited looks unvisited, and the one I haven't visited looks visited. Can you guess which is which?

[image: reverse visited colours]

Comment: Lucky it's not a strikethrough. ;-)

Comment: Since you've posted on "New colors launched" thread, looks like the upper one is visited.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ It does, doesn't it! Yet this was taken before clicking the link. I had visited the layoffs one.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394030/165261

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 491*

In the revision history of a question, the color of the gold badge icon next to a user is too dark and is almost indistinguishable from the color of the bronze badge icon:

[image]

Normal-looking colors in the top bar:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The vertical alignment of question score to question title in the Linked/Related sections looks very odd when the text only takes up a single line:

[image: Screenshot of the Linked section showing a title misaligned with the question score]

Less of an issue, but in the same area: Question scores with an accepted answer are fractionally taller than questions without (as the green box has a `1px` border that the grey box does not):

[image: Comparison of two question score elements]

(It's possible this has always been the case, but I could swear they used to line up)

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### Very poor distinction of visited inline links

The colour for visited links is so close to the normal text colour as to be practically indistinguishable

| Visited Link |
| --- |
| [image: visited link dark mode] |
| [image: visited link light mode] |

For comparison, here is the same link in the un-visited state

| Un-visited Link |
| --- |
| [image: unvisited link dark mode] |
| [image: unvisited link light mode] |

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The <kbd>Looking for your Teams?</kbd> button in the left sidebar has the left part of the border chopped off. Could it be updated to have the border go all the way around it?

[image: Screenshot of bug with freehand red circle]

Comment: Oh interesting, I don't see that outer glow / border unless I right-click.

Comment: (Or single-click, to trigger the dialog, which was... unexpected.)

Comment: Looks like this is fixed now, thanks for reporting. Cause was related to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393950/888623

Answer (score 7):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref logged with Teams — not color related*

Not sure if this is allowed as it's about SOfT, but... it's a bugs thread, so I'll post anyways. Possibly bad practice to have a wall of bugs as one answer, but... I don't know if SOfT is fair game here, so I'd rather not post a bunch of answers, especially when IDK if it's related.

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When an SOfT instance has a long title, it escapes the box! May I suggest it wraps the text instead?

Technically speaking, it *kinda* wrapped the text before:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

It looks slightly better now, as the rest of the SOfT instance title is readable, but it still seems *wrong*. Could this please be updated so the title doesn't simply escape the box and does something else instead?

Bonus: now when you hover over something else, if the current one is too long, the one you're hovering over also escapes the box.

It also appears the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the top right (to create a Team) now escapes the box! Can it... uh... stay in the box? Might be a good idea to change it to a different color (white?) too.

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Aside from the navbar at the top, the `/for-you` page ignores high-contrast in dark mode and simply renders normal dark mode. I don't know if this is a *new* issue, though.

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Under `/users`, the borders look strange

[image]

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Also don't know if this is new, but "Add a tagDone" looks strange - could those be updated to be actual buttons? Or, if they were intended to be links, could some space be added between them?

[image]

Comment: huh... i kinda like it escaping the box, if only when it's hovered over and then when not hovered shrink back down to fit within the box, hiding the text oveflow

Comment: "Also don't know if this is new, but "Add a tagDone" looks strange" – That's definitely not new. The main bug report about it is here: [Tag watching & ignoring is bugged in the profile page settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385385/335251)

Answer (score 7):

### Oddly jarring colour changes of new posts notification in high contrast dark mode

The colours for normal:
[image: Normal new post notification in high contrast dark mode.]

hover:
[image: Hovered new post notification in high contrast dark mode.]

and click:
[image: Clicked new post notification in high contrast dark mode.]

of the post notifications are rather dissonant and highly distracting. Especially the shift to and from clicked looks **very jarring**

[image: Animation showing the transition from normal, to hovered, then finally clicked new post notification which leads to an abrupt flash of bright colour when clicking.]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Well, this is even worse (seen on [this revision page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/393963/revisions):

[image: seemingly padding-less tag]

I first thought, it was just the padding-less green-ish stipe but there's actually a border I can hardly see on my screen. I only noticed it due to hovering over it.

[image: hovered state]

It's just the diffing, I understand, but this shouldn't be more prominent than the actual tag itself.

Comment: Related (since I think it's the same shade on both revised text and the tags): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393984

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When I touch the edit button it turns black. If I *edit* the post it's natural that the button remains black for me (to show it's edited). But if I *don't* edit the post and click on the back button, the edit button is still black for me. In this case even if I reload the page the button is still black. Does it remain black to show me I once clicked on the edit button on that post?

[image: edit1]

[image: edit2]

This occurs on Meta and all other SE sites. I hadn't seen this prior to the recent global changes in sites.

**Update**: It should be fixed so that only when I actually edit the post the button remains black. Because if it remains black as I once opened the edit page and closed it without editing I will wrongly think that I have edited the post after I encountered it later.

Comment: Well that's typical for using back button so not sure if considered a bug. Can also reproduce on desktop if middle clicking with a mouse to open edit in new tab, the edit link stays in "active" state.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry I have edited my answer with more sentences.

Comment: Also, you are speaking about letting the edit page to remain opened in a new tab. But I'm speaking about "not editing" and clicking on the back button.

Comment: Looks like they applied it to the `visited` state of the link,  not sure how it was before. But yeah, once you visit the link once, the color will stay black for good, on the same browser. It doesn't check if you actually edited or not.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### Inconsistent colouring between Stack Snippets editor and code blocks in posts

The Stack Overflow snippets editor uses the *bleached* colours  but when the code is displayed in the post, it is back to its glorious, vibrant self .

It's more noticeable in dark mode but inconsistent in both.

#### Snippets editor

| Dark Mode | Light Mode |
| --- | --- |
| [image: snippets editor dark mode] | [image: snippets editor light mode] |

#### Post

| Dark Mode | Light Mode |
| --- | --- |
| [image: code block dark mode] | [image: code block light mode] |

Answer (score 6):

In the "Next tag badge" in profile page and  inside the "Select your next badge" window the tags has the grey color only.

Screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

MSE questions at https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime still use the old design:

> [image]

So do the ones shown at the favorite-tag filter, as well as in its dropdown (* show details):

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

### Unread responses in the responses tab have a much darker background color

It appears that the background color for unread responses in one's own profile's Responses tab has become darker, reducing contrast:

[image]

Can this be made lighter again?

Comment: I've added a new 'answer' encompassing this & many others similar. The overall problem is the *orange*, everywhere it appears it's *way* too much.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not using any theme modifications; my experience is based on, and my feedback is aimed at only unmodified, vanilla, SE-provided themes.

**Increased contrast:**

To me it seems that by a design choice, contrast had been increased in a lot of such places where it does not serve the user well.

I percieve, a lot of contrast had been added to elements where the overall result is **only distraction**, percieved visual clutter, which needs a constant, straining effort to ignore, so that one can keep concentrating on one's primary activity on the page.

It is emphasized by the apparent circumstance that the contrast-increasing changes had been rolled out on supporting-role UI elements (like the now-obsidian-black page header strip, and *some* tags), but not on primary-importance elements.

(E.g. the "Post your answer" button, which is the primary action in my use case (posting this answer), is being not only competed, but defeated, by the prominence of the strip of tags underneath it.)

**Lost contrast:**

I see a lot of reports where contrast was lost, out of which, I assume, a lot of cases are unintentional, things being overlooked: **bugs**.

However, the apparent number of such bugs seems to suggest that the code is not in a tidy state; where implementing *a consistent sweep around the codebase does not any more promise consistent results*, because things might have been done in inconsistent ways.

If that assessment would indeed be accurate, I would advocate for giving priority to tidying up the codebase. Trying to roll out major changes platform-wide on a brittle, untidy codebase could become a burnout-inducing struggle (especially while under the pressure of high expectations), costing in the end more than an initial tidy-up would have costed. (Also: such a tidy-up could contribute to the development / maintenance of an aware [interface inventory](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/interface-inventory/).)

Comment: I know you should [never rewrite software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/), but… I don't see a way forwards other than a full rewrite of the front-end, taking into account modern HTML (and a corresponding change in what's considered idiomatic Stacks). I'm not sure whether the company has the workforce for that, but if they're willing to open-source Stacks they might be willing to open-source this hypothetical front-end rewrite, and get community contributors to pitch in.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Firing a significant part of your work force and replacing them with unpaid volunteers is probably illegal in most of the world, even in USA. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337117/is-stack-exchange-in-violation-of-new-york-labor-law-in-using-volunteer-moderat

Comment: @Lundin I've been pitching this since before the last two layoffs – for "lack of expertise" reasons rather than lack of personnel –, so they'd have a decent argument that it's unrelated. Plus, if they didn't claim copyright over the work (only used it under license, same as a load of other libraries they're currently using) it'd be hard to argue we were working _for_ them, any more than any CC BY-SA 4.0 contributor is working _for_ them. Having volunteer moderators is a far more dubious practice than having open source volunteers, which even Microsoft does these days.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Or them open source volunteers could just join the 100% open source, 100% non-profit alternative at codidact.com? Why involve some private company?

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the [tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags), when hovering the `required-tag` button on top, it gets a very bright background and the white text becomes almost unreadable:

[image: required tag unreadable when hovered]

Should be changed so it's the same as hovering an actual required tag, e.g.

[image: actual required tag with a proper hover color]

Answer (score 6):

Usercards and comments for the Asker on MSO are a bit dark for the text colors within

[image: Large user card on MSO]
[image: Comment user card on MSO]

Seems fine on Stack Overflow proper?

[image: Large user card on SO]
[image: Comment user card on SO]

Answer (score 5):

### Response to the Feedback on Dark Mode

We did test the homepage in dark mode. It's working as intended in the APCA contrast that the Community wanted. We've heard your feedback and are looking into toning it down. However, if we execute on that, there is a good chance we will no longer meet the APCA goal that the community decided on, so we need to be thoughtful about any changes. Luckily, all of the work that has gone into this release has made it easier to switch our colors around. We'll let you know what we land on and when we deploy.

Comment: Based on the [previous post](/q/390761/401803) about colors change, I'd say that [the suggested screenshot of Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nToV5.png) is **very** different from the [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFzqi.png). I wouldn't say the latter was "working as intended". Seriously, we **just accessed the home page** and immediately noticed that everything was unreadable. It's really hard to believe that this was properly tested.

Comment: Contrast IMO isn't the problem, it's a complete lack of vibrancy. Every light colour is tending towards white. It looks bleached. Also, what's this about "what the community wanted"? Could you please link to the reference for that?

Comment: Shouldn't the actual "high contrast" mode be the mode that meets contrast accessibility standards? While the regular dark mode should simply be an aesthetically pleasing website with a dark background. I find the amount of contrast on the Stackoverflow dark mode so high now that it quickly causes me eye strain.

Comment: @DBS I completely disagree. I think there are issues (bugs) with the current dark mode where dark colors on top of other dark colors (for example tag buttons on the dark background), and light colors on top of, or adjacent to, other light colors that make the individual elements hard to distinguish (washed out), while there are also issues with the extremely light colors (links) contrasting too highly with the dark background, causing eye strain for lots of people. Both are legitimate complaints that should not be discounted just because at first glance they may sound as if they conflict.

Comment: I completely agree with Phil above; it's less a contrast problem and more a saturation one, at least for me personally. Before the change, dark mode had colors and indicators that were easily distinguishable by color– now, nearly every colored element leans towards white, which makes everything feel washed out and more dull by comparison. I imagine this is even worse for folks with high contrast settings on their monitor.

Comment: I still want to know how many people in the community really wanted an APCA contrast dark mode, compared the the total number of people on the site using dark mode, and why that had to be done in the regular dark mode theme, instead of the high-contrast dark mode theme. I think the majority of people were really happy with the StackOverflow dark mode theme as it was.

Comment: Seems kinda weird to me to see that the community wanted APCA, when i haven't heard of that, and am probably among the most active meta users.... there's no way i missed a post somewhere. I use darkmode almost everywhere, but SO's dark mode has never been appealing to me. You've done a *great* job with the blog's dark mode design, and even so labs, but i still can't stand SO's dark mode... neither before or after.

Comment: Counterpoint: the contrast/saturation home page looks _mostly_ fine to me in dark mode (other pages, less so).  If something is saturated, there should be a _reason_, in terms of emphasizing important content. For example, the green on the answer indicator is washed out, _and that's good_, because it's not that important to the page as a whole. It doesn't jump out, _because it shouldn't_. If there's one thing I'd want to jump out more, it's [the indicators for content in watched tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLPSk.png).  These should jump out as things I should be looking at, and they don't.

Comment: Please, just make one theme with pale colors for APCA and other one with bright colors like previously for normal people! Theme with current changes looks like I have problems with my eyes...

Comment: @Phil, As far as I can tell, the first mention of APCA is [in this highly upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386167/160917), and then there is subsequent discussion in [this post from staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390761/160917).

Comment: Even if the community really wanted APCA and voted for it, I'm pretty sure nobody was expecting it to be implemented like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFzqi.png). If that's what APCA looks like, I prefer to not have it

Comment: @D.W. thanks for that link. Looking at the screenshots of what they said the StackOverflow dark mode was going to look like, they still had the StackOverflow "orange" color in those screenshots, and dark text on light backgrounds was bolded, neither of which is the case in the final result. Also their screenshots left out tons of things, like notification badges, and the color of visited links. The color of the pagination buttons in the screenshot was also different. I would say what was upvoted and approved by people was not what they actually delivered.

Comment: are you sure the community wanted APCA dark mode? Based on what statistics/requests? Fro the actual response on this threads it seems really the opposite

Comment: “High contrast” is not the only visual accessibility requirement that exists. That's _why_ software designed for usability (e.g. Windows 98) has high contrast themes, rather than making everything high-contrast by default. (Saying nothing new, but saying it slightly differently.)

Comment: Can you please add the colored Stack Overflow logo to Dark mode? Since its introduction we've been stuck with a bland white logo. There's no reason why it can't be white 'Stack' and orange 'Overflow' or something more interesting...

Comment: I think folks trying to make an enemy of APCA are misunderstanding the situation to some degree; prior to APCA, the only major accessibility metric/ measure for font contrast was specified by WCAG 2, [which has notable drawbacks that APCA directly aims to address](https://github.com/Myndex/SAPC-APCA/blob/master/documentation/WhyAPCA.md). The problem here appears to be less about APCA, and more about _an approach that apparently optimized for the accessibility metric rather than the overall experience_. That's not APCA's fault, especially if it provides a genuinely better measure of contrast.

Comment: The goal of [APCA and accessibility in general is usability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386167); using APCA in a way that ends up with a _less_ usable, more washed out interface/ experience isn't APCA's fault– it's a fault of losing sight of the end goal while applying the standard.

Comment: Leaving it here for decision makers: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/

Current dark mode looks more like what you guys were trying to avoid in this blog post's image captioned "We'd have to do better than this"

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[image]

Can the SE logo be vertically centered? IMO, we don’t need it there, but if it is there, it should likely be centered with everything else

Comment: I doubt it's related to these changes.

Answer (score 4):

The colors of the mod tags look a lot like the colors of the staff label on users.

[image]

Due to the color changes, I thought the tags were entirely new ones, staff-exclusive. Will this be confusing?

Answer (score 4):

### Code blocks need darker background on white theme

I can barely see the light gray here.

(Regarding the comments: I haven't performed any color calibration, nor adjusted the display color profile in any way. There are no userscripts running, and this is a fresh Linux installation. I believe a good design should still look ok on consumer-grade hardware.)

[image: pic]

Comment: I think this is similar to your other answer. I think it's a local screen-contrast issue, not a global site issue. Your image here shows the grey as 246,246,246 If I make a new code block here I get 220,220,220, which is perfectly acceptable. I only just spotted your other post also has a screen-cap which is already lighter than the actual site colours, so I definitely think you have a profiling/calibration issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is a fresh manjaro install, I didn't touch any monitor settings, color profiles are disabled. I'd wait for more people to confirm what color they get. My only guess is that it could depend on the browser (FF here).

Comment: If profiling is disabled… you have no colour-matching in place at all. What you actually see is really nothing more than 'random chance'. No display is perfect out of the box. Even manufacturer-provided profiles are an approximation of many different physical displays.

Comment: That looks like a perfectly acceptable subtle-background on my setup.

Answer (score 4):

Some sites look all bleak and blurry now, to the point where it is affecting visibility. When I launched https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ this morning I sincerely thought my monitor was acting up, because the colors and contrast were suddenly all bleak and seemingly of low resolution. I can't really pin-point it, I think it's related to poor choice of font colors on the post headlines, but it seems that all fonts in general are of much lower resolution now somehow.

Whereas https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ looks OK, as does SO etc.

Kindly rollback whatever changes you did to https://electronics.stackexchange.com since it is literally painful for the eyes. As anyone can tell, making the sites less readable isn't an improvement and that's not something that needs discussion or tweaking either - just rollback the changes. The site was fine before.

Comment: I am not following; it looks fine to me. Could you add a screenshot about what you find to be so bleak or blurry, so I can better understand?

Comment: @SpencerG All of it...? As I said I can't pin-point it or I'd post a screenshot. I just know that as a regular visitor of the site, when I opened the site in my web browser this morning, I thought my monitor was malfunctioning. You'll need a before/after pic to tell, I guess.

Comment: @SpencerG Maybe just open https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ side by side on the same monitor. One looks very nice and readable, one looks bleached and low contrast.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When you go to a site you haven't previously visited, there is a small introduction.

In the introduction, there is a close button, as shown here:

[image: Dialog with almost invisble X button]

Can you see the close button? No? Some cropping has made it easier to find than in the actual dialog. Still no? Here it is:

[image: Same dialog but with the X button pointed out]

**Please make the close button easily visible.**

This point has been raised before and not fixed, but as the colours are new, it may be a new bug.

Comment: [already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391737/close-button-for-join-this-community-banner-is-too-low-contrast) 100% the same, this one isn't related to the recent change so should not be reported here.

Comment: It's the sort of thing that revamping the colors to increase contrast _should have_ addressed, but didn't.  I think it's legitimate to report here.

Comment: There was an issue with the banner using dark themed colors but the buttons still using light themed colors. We've applied the proper overrides and the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @Carog Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Least on meta.stackexchange, especially on the front page - the ultra-saturated mandatory tags are *glaring* Its unlikely to affect any other site - and even if it fits accessibility guidelines, it affects usability of the site for some.

Comment: *possible duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393955/152859)*

Answer (score 3):

### Need darker background for tags on light theme

The tag background is almost white, I have a hard time discerning it from the white background.

(Regarding the comments: I haven't performed any color calibration, nor adjusted the display color profile in any way. There are no userscripts running, and this is a fresh Linux installation.)

[image: pic]

Comment: It's pale, but it doesn't bother me. It does its job as a highlight, unlike a lot of the new ones which have been punched up to 'garish'. I see RGB 225,232,239 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np8S4.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin Maybe this depends on the monitor. I've had the same issue at work, with designers using increasingly pale colors. :P Maybe the contrast is better or more expensive monitors.

Comment: I have a fully colour-calibrated rig here, so I know I'm seeing [to within one digit] what the designers intended. Many displays at factory defaults are over-contrasty [because it makes them look better on the shop floor] & if yours is just tipping towards the lighter end on that pale blue, then yes, it will start to vanish for you. I've mocked up what can happen with an over-contrasty screen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GckvY.jpg - it's exaggerated for emphasis, but I can now **just** see the pale blue in this.

Comment: I only just noticed your screen-cap here is also lighter than the actual site colours - it should be 229,235,243 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4awUW.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin Just rechecked without userscripts, and the color stays as it was on my screenshot.

Comment: Then you have a calibration/profiling issue local to that machine.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) *ref 489*

The MathJax wrapping bug is now back after these color changes. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: A user profile from Math.SE where MathJax wraps awkwardly in the Questions tab]

This is the same bug as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375745/mathjax-layout-problems-persist-in-all-actions-tab-and-review-queues?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372605#372605), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369812/mathjax-text-broken-along-several-lines-in-post-titles-in-review-queues). Reproduction details: Windows 10, both Chrome and Edge (latest versions as of this post).

Comment: @Carog if this helps the team looking in to it, [here's a live link to the profile in the screenshot, which still has the bug occurring for me](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/274536/mathisnice1729?tab=topactivity).

Comment: Thank you! Links to live examples in the code always help a lot, appreciate it.