# In Chrome, using chrome://flags/ : #enable-force-dark causes the input textarea scrollbar to be nearly invisible

Tags: bug, design, editor, google-chrome

In the following GIF, when an extra line is added to the input text, it becomes too large for the input area, so the browser adds a scrollbar. Unfortunately, the scrollbar is nearly the same color as the input area background, which makes the scrollbar nearly invisible and effectively unusable.

Example:

[image]

I use Chrome 118 with Windows 10. I don't know if that behavior stems from Chrome or SE.

Text used (sic):

> I have an iPhone 12 mini that uses iOS 15 that uses iOS 15. It uses an eSIM cars. I would like to use that eSIM card on another phone.

The example was on https://apple.stackexchange.com with chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`.

Comment: If you look extremely closely on the right edge of the text area, or use a color picker to extract the color values, you'll see that the shade of black changes ever so slightly, because a scrollbar pops up.

Comment: While there is a bug here, the issue isn't as described in this question. The issue is that the new colors make the scrollbar nearly invisible. While the issue is probably related to the changes described in "[New colors launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393939/271271)", the question in the screen recording doesn't appear to be on-topic for Stack Overflow, so it's unclear if you are using the SE stock dark mode on SO or you are using some third party capability to have a dark mode on a site other than SO.

Comment: @Makyen I use https://apple.stackexchange.com with chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`

Comment: VTC: what's unclear or need details? If the VTC came from Makyen, please give me a few minutes to address you comment before VTC.

Comment: @Makyen [possibly related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394022/339911)

Comment: The "line split" is just how the browser handles text overflow, no bug. As others said, the actual bug is something else, so this bug report is wrong, i.e. doesn't focus/describe the actual bug. (didn't vote to close.)

Comment: Ok I revised the post based on the comments.

Comment: Better, thanks. While it was already reported as answer to the still fresh announcement, from way too many experiences, it will just stay there and have to be reported again so this one here is legit.

Comment: But isn't this due to Chrome, plain and simple? I force Dark Mode through Dark Reader, and [complained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394004/422926) about that too, but how is this an SE bug?

Comment: @Joachim couldn't SE make their CSS more compatible with Chrome?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Waiting to vote/flag for closure on the chance that the OP will provide more information and make changes isn't how close votes are supposed to work. Users should vote/flag for closure based on the current state of the question, not on a state the potential close voter *hopes* the question will eventually take. Aside from that, at the time of my comment, you'd already had almost 1.5 hours from the initial comment by Sonic indicating that the entire premise of the question was inaccurate, so I'm unsure what additional time you feel should be given prior to voting to close.

Comment: As to the issue being something that's actually a bug in SE's software and that SE wants to address, it's unclear to me if SE considers the use of `#enable-force-dark` in Chrome to be supported by SE sites. If that's a supported mode is something for which the company needs to make the determination. However, regardless of if SE wants to try to address it, it's *definitely* a bug in Chrome and should be reported as such the the Chromium project, because the use of `#enable-force-dark` shouldn't result in the page being, effectively, unusable, regardless of the CSS in the page.

Comment: For what it's worth, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393962/299995) bug report was created on the "new colors launched" update and was tagged with `status-planned`. Although that was for the actual SO dark mode, perhaps when that is fixed it will also resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't think that this should be tagged as [tag:bug] because Chrome flags are a way to handle Chrome's features that haven't been released to the general public.   There are risks related to using them, Ref. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/chrome-flags/. Because of this, supporting a Chrome flag should be declared somewhere. If there is no such declaration, then this might be off-topic here. [tag:bug] should not be used for third-party, in this case Chrome, bugs.