# Did the purple highlight just get worse?

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, user-interface, highlighting

I just refreshed a page on [MusicSE](https://music.stackexchange.com), which got a nasty purple highlight after the recent colour changes - see [New colors launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched) - to be presented with an even darker purple on a new contributor user card.

I can't get a screenshot of the 'before' page, but this jumped right out at me as I refreshed the only one I did have open.

[image]

I'm pretty sure that's going to fail any legibility rules, aside from looking truly horrible on a site where the colour hints are predominantly yellow.
I'm posting here not MusicSE as I'm sure this is going to affect any site with similar global parameters. This is my only regular site where this purple has been emphasised with the new colour changes.

I just realised, not just new contributor, every user card; this from my own card

[image]

---

Well, this is the fix… still way too purple for me:\

[image]

Comment: Not that ugly, but also very little contrast on Math SE.

Comment: I'm not a user of MathSE, but a quick check shows it's got the more common blue rather than this new purple. I agree it's also too dark, though.

Comment: Here is a wayback machine link to a question you can use for the screenshot for "before": https://web.archive.org/web/20220818180015/https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15221/whats-the-point-of-keys-other-than-c-and-am. It appears to have been a light gray color before.

Comment: Also, I think the correct identifier for those things is "user card", not to be confused with actual badges (bronze, silver, gold symbols). By the way, I get a headache trying to make out the silver badge symbol for Theodore.

Comment: We actually just pushed a fix for this issue (along with a few others) — just waiting for the build to go through. Hang tight!

Comment: Please be nice to purple. They deserve our love as well ....

Comment: @Carog: I assume this push is network-wide and not just for [music.se]...?

Comment: I only wanted to see you
Laughing in the purple rain
Purple rain, purple rain....

Comment: @CaveJohnson - user card, yes. I knew it wasn't badge [hence the inverted commas] I just couldn't think what is was. BTW, I think the colour had already changed to purple recently, it just wasn't so heavy. I couldn't find anything recent enough on wayback, unfortunately, only front pages, which don't display this user card.

Comment: @Carog - I've added an image of the fix… ermmm… can we get it any better than this. Grey the colour out a bit so it's not quite so in your face?

Comment: Regarding the edit: now it's at least not terrible, and no longer a bug. I think best course of action is to start feature request on the per-site meta, asking to change the color or even revert the change, at least for the user card.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry - worth a shot - https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3984/can-we-ask-staff-for-a-new-colour-scheme

Comment: The cookie pop-up (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx3Hc.png) is painful

Comment: @Carog: What about [this difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjSvX.png)? Visible to people who aren't part of [music.se].

Comment: @Werner The fix did go out network wide but it was in regards to the shade of color used (background should now be lighter on user cards). There seems to be another issue with theme overrides here (what used to be a grey background is now purple). I've logged that as it's own issue to be investigated. I'll check the other SE sites for any color differences here too.

Comment: @Werner The buttons in the top banner would be a separate issue — logged in the backlog to be reviewed. Ideally, this would be it's own feature-request if you wanted to keep track of it's status/progress (but at least I have it listed).

Comment: @Carog - thanks for the heads up. Could you drop a note onto https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3984/can-we-ask-staff-for-a-new-colour-scheme for those not following main meta. Thank you.